# Testing MvvmCross.Core projects

Tags: .net, xamarin, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I have a solution with a Core and an Android project. I wish to create a Core.Tests project, to test my viewmodels. I add it as a Class Library (as described in http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/n29-testing-n1-days-of-mvvmcross.html).

I have the following NuGet packages installed:

```
App.Core:
  "MvvmCross"

App.Core.Tests:
  "MvvmCross Test Helpers"

App.Droid:
  "MvvmCross"
```

With this setup, im getting an error when trying to test my viewodel(s):

> The type 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModel' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'Cirrious.MvvmCross, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=e16445fd9b451819'

Im not sure how to resolve this (Simply adding the "MvvmCross" nuget package to Core.Tests does *not* work, as the Core.Tests project is not a PCL project, but instead a class library project. Trying to add the MvvmCross nuget package causes it to start referencing WPF stuff, making the build fail with:

> Project file must include the .NET Framework assembly 'WindowsBase,
>   PresentationCore, PresentationFramework' in the reference list.

Unforunately in the n+29 video, "We just let ReSharper pull in the assemblies" - But which are these? I do not use ReSharper. How do i get this properly setup? http://youtu.be/kQdZW9hQoi4?t=14m35s

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I can add the WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework dll's to the test project, but is this really the most ideal solution? I have platform-specific test projects already, i want to have one solely for testing my core project. I dont need WPF stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting this project wrong as it appears you are noticing on your last edit.  This project should just be a .Net 4.5 library with nunit and moq installed.  Look at the example here at the source code for the lesson you are referencing:

https://github.com/MvvmCross/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-29-TipCalcTest/TipCalcTest.Tests

This project should have mostly the same nugets as your core project plus nunit and moq.